# Why weren't Kise and Midorima able to get in the Zone?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

According to the anime,

> The Zone, in this state of extreme focus, all unnecessary thoughts disappear and the athlete becomes absorbed in his play. Only those who have practiced and practiced, earn the right to stand before the door and it'll open up.

Since it's shown that Kise and Midorima have practiced more than Aomine and were the members of Generations of Miracles, they were still not able to get in the Zone.

Why?

Comment: Midorima did not got his zone because he would become **overpowered** and no one in the world can stop his shoots. He would probably **the best and the strongest player** in the entire series.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zYXV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zYXV.jpg)

Comment: This isn't a reason, so in order to make protagonist stronger than him, mangaka didn't gave him the ability of zone XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kise

> has already been shown to enter the Zone in the fight against
>  Jabberwock. ***(Read: Kuroko no Basuke: Last Game)***

During his state, he can freely copy all moves including moves that he wasn't capable of using, which were moves by Generation of Miracles-tier.

> He used the Zone in conjunction with his Perfect Copy Ability amping
>  up all the skills he currently has.

It is stated in the manga that those who have a ***passion*** for the game can enter the Zone. This is shown that even though it appears that Murasakibara had shown a dislike for basketball, that he also, indeed loves to play basketball too. This is **one** of the *pre-requisite to enter the zone*.

Knowing Midorima, he can't enter the Zone as he is as of now. He thinks of basketball as nothing more than just a game that he's good at. There's a probability that he can enter the Zone considering he is already is a GoM. All he has to do is to have strong passion/love for Basketball.