# Kuroko no basuke - Last Game : why does Akashi cant put everyone into the zone?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

The episode between rakuzan vs seirin match, Akashi put his teammates in a zone state (on the 4th quarter I think). My question is why he didn't use it against team jabberwock in the movie? As far as I know, generation of miracles players has the capability to enter the zone. It would be a great match if they all go in zone. Anyways, if someone know why it didn't happened let me hear your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related or duplicate? [Why weren't Kise and Midorima able to get in the Zone?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/44513/2516)

Comment: i think its a different story @AkiTanaka